# In need to either convert Spring's default HAL format to JSON API, or make Ember Data accept HAL json format

Tags: json, spring, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

My Ember.js front-end application is to consume REST API created in Spring (Boot). The problem is:
- Spring returns json response in HAL format
- Ember Data expect the response to be fully compliant with JSON API specs

So far I have found that there are at least two "adapters" for each side.

This one is supposed to convince Ember Data to use the Spring's response as it is:
[ember-data-hal-9000](https://github.com/201-created/ember-data-hal-9000)

This one makes Spring's response compliant with JSON API specs:
[Katharsis - HATEOAS for Java based on JSON API standard](http://katharsis.io/)

I've read that both have its own problems but has anyone successfully employed either of them? Ideally both of them, so a comparison can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked for a client for a while who had gone with Katharsis. The backend developers disliked Katharsis (as it had made some non-spec compliant "decisions" that had to be worked around), but part of that may also have been due to a fairly messy backend data model.

It worked great on the Ember side of things

Comment: I decided to try Katharsis, I found some good examples of how to use it with Spring Boot. Pasting it here for anyone else that might need it: https://www.codenotfound.com/2017/04/json-api-spring-boot-katharsis-example.html